# Grep a set of values appearing multiple times in a file and display in a specific way

Tags: shell, grep

I am new to shell scripting.I have a below mentioned requirement.
INPUT FILE 1

```
START
A X|
M Q|
B Y|
C Z|
D U|

END
```

INPUT FILE 2

```
START 
A X1|
M Q1|
B Y1|
C Z1|
D U1|
END
START
A X2|
M Q2
B Y2|
C Z2|
D U2|
END
```

Expected output

```
X,Y,Z
X1,Y1,Z1
X2,Y2,Z2
```

The files are ranging from few MBS to 10 GB.
I tried a few combination of

```
grep -f patternfile file1....N >> file.txt
```

Awk and transpose 
Is there any more effective way for doing the same with performance not getting  hampered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what you want to do is, find `A`, `B` and `C` in each file and create lines from each of them? What kind of tools can you use?

Comment: Thanks Tamas for your response. The line is actually a key value pair . I want to extract all the values for specified keys in the specified format.

Answer (score 0):

To get values for keys `A`, `B` and `C` use the following ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$1~/^(A|B|C)$/{ sub("\\|","",$2); s=($1=="C")?"\n":","; printf "%s%s",$2,s }' file[12]
```

The output:

```
X,Y,Z
X1,Y1,Z1
X2,Y2,Z2
```